# Drupal update to 7.51 - I can't drag and drop tables anymore

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Just updated my Drupal to latest version of 7.51 and I don't seem to be able to drag and drop tables now. Anyone know how to fix or what the cause is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the file 'misc/tabledrag.js' has been changed and that's the cause:-

```
`// Add the mousedown action for the handle.
  --277handle.mousedown(function (event) {
  ++279handle.bind('mousedown touchstart pointerdown', function (event) {
  ++280if (event.originalEvent.type == "touchstart") {
  ++281event = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
  ++282}`
```

Nothing wrong with that change but the mouseCoords on line 588 is looking for 'clientX' and 'clientY' they don't exist on the the pointerdown event. I found that changing:-

```
x: event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft,
y: event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop  - document.body.clientTop
```

to

```
x: event.originalEvent.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft,
y: event.originalEvent.clientY + document.body.scrollTop  - document.body.clientTop
```

fixed it, not sure if it's right but I'll be patching my sites to this until it's fixed in the next release!

**EDIT**

A patch has now been created here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2821441